# Nullable argument for kotlin "remove"

Tags: kotlin

I'm just trying to understand a little more about Kotlin nullable type declarations.
The type declaration of [`MutableList.remove`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove.html) is:

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<out T>.remove(element: T): Boolean
```

However the following compiles and runs even though the inferred type of `myBook` is `Stuff?` and its value is `null`.

```
data class Stuff(val name: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myListOfStuff: ArrayList<Stuff> = arrayListOf(
            Stuff("bed"),
            Stuff("backpack"),
            Stuff("lunch")
    )
    val myBook = myListOfStuff.find { it.name == "book" }
    val found = myListOfStuff.remove(myBook)
    println(myListOfStuff)
}
```

Why doesn't the `remove` type declaration use the nullable `T?` type, something like this?

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<out T>.remove(element: T?): Boolean
```

Or perhaps more precisely how does the `out` modifier make it possible for `T` to be nullable?

Comment: Now, just wondering, can the `MutableList` contain a null? Or that's a no go? The remove method gets described at, removes an item from the list, if it is present (and returns true if it did), so I guess having a null there might not be problematic?

Comment: If I declared it as `ArrayList<Stuff?>` it could contain nulls, but not as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type T in

```
  fun <T> MutableCollection<out T>.remove(element: T): Boolean
```

is inferred as `Stuff?`. Your line

```
  val found = myListOfStuff.remove(myBook)
```

tries to remove all occurrences of `null` as `myBook` is null. It obviously can't find any but the compiler does not mind.

The `out` keyword ensures to the compiler that no functions like `add(element)` will be called (`add(null)` would be a problem), just functions that return `T` like `get()`.

See this to clarify:

```
data class Stuff(val name: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myListOfStuff: ArrayList<Stuff?> = arrayListOf(
            Stuff("bed"),
            Stuff("backpack"),
            Stuff("lunch"),
            null
    )
    println(myListOfStuff)
    val found = myListOfStuff.remove(null)
    println(myListOfStuff)
}
```

Output:

```
[Stuff(name=bed), Stuff(name=backpack), Stuff(name=lunch), null]
[Stuff(name=bed), Stuff(name=backpack), Stuff(name=lunch)]
```

For the `out` keyword see here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Comment: So you're saying that the compiler infers T as being String? first, then the function can be applied to the MutableList<String> because the out covariance makes so that MutableList<String?> be a supertype of MutableList<String>, since String? is a supertype of String. Did I get this right? So remove will use the comparison from the supertype class?

Comment: If I understood you correctly then yes, you got this right. But I don't understand what you mean with "So remove will use the comparison from the supertype class?".

Comment: I think I got it. Since `T` will be inferred as `String?`, the remove function can call `T get()` on the `MutableCollection<String>` and assign it to a `String?` variable and then make the comparison with the parameter passed (which is also `String?`). Then maybe I'm wrong, type covariance is crazy.

Comment: Correct, just that it's `Stuff?` and not `String?`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, you are not actually calling the member function remove you refer to but rather the following extension function:

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<out T>.remove(element: T): Boolean
```

Comment: Ahh I think you're on the right track. Could you spell this out more explicitly?  It's not very clear to me how to connect the `out` modifier to the original question.

Comment: @mjhm everything works the way you would expect it. so, your thinking is completely correct. you're just confused because an extension function is called and not the function you expected to be called. if you use intellij: hold ctrl and click on the remove function. the ide will bring you to the code definition which can be found in CollectionsKt.class

Comment: Thanks for answering, I modified my original question. What I was asking seems to be confusing since I had the wrong function signature.