# Kotlin non nullable map allows remove null

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, nullable

Why this code can be compiled and executed without erros?

```
val map = HashMap<Int, Long>()
val key :Int? = null
map.remove(key)
```

In MutableMap *remove* declared as accepting only non nullable key, so it shouldn't even compile. Is it a Kotlin type inference bug or am I missing something?

```
public fun remove(key: K): V?
```

Comment: you call `HashMap.remove`, no?

Comment: It is legal as long as you haven't tried to `put(key, 1)` ;-). You could remove this key, but you cannot create an entry with it, so no need to worry about this.

Comment: Adding MutableMap interface gives the same result.


I think it's not about how Map works, it's about how this method call is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `map.remove(key)` doesn't not calls

```
public fun remove(key: K): V?
```

It calls an extension `remove` function:

```
public inline fun <@OnlyInputTypes K, V> MutableMap<out K, V>.remove(key: K): V? =
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (this as MutableMap<K, V>).remove(key)
```

This function documentation says that it *allows to overcome type-safety restriction of `remove` that requires to pass a key of type `K`.*

---

It allows overcoming type-safety restriction because the key of the entry you are removing does not have to be the same type as the object that you pass into `remove(key)`; the specification of the method only requires that they be equal. This follows from how the `equals()` method takes in an `Any` as a parameter, not just the same type as the object.

Although it may be commonly true that many classes have `equals()` defined so that its objects can only be equal to objects of its own class, there are many places where this is not the case. For example, the specification for `List.equals()` says that two `List` objects are equal if they are both `List`s and have the same contents, even if they are different implementations of `List`. So, for example, according to the specification of the method, it is possible to have a `MutableMap<ArrayList<Something>, Something>` and call `remove(key)` with a `LinkedList` as an argument, and it should retrieve the key which is a list with the same contents. This would not be possible if this extension `remove(key)` didn't exist.<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859239/10536125)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Your code is perfectly fine as `remove()` allows nullable arguments - your map **contents** definition got nothing to it. When `remove()` is invoked, it would try to find matching requested key in the map and as it's not there (it's completely irrelevant why it's not there - it's valid case for key to be not present) nothing will happen. Where compiler will complain is on any attempt to **put** such key into your map. Then map definition kicks in and since it's known that nullable keys not allowed, such code won't even compile as this is clearly buggy code.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin could warn or refuse to compile (would be good), but it doesn't (for now).

The reason for it being not as bad as it looks from a first glance is that you cannot `put` an `Int?` into a `MutableMap<Int, Long>` because

```kotlin
val map = HashMap<Int, Long>()
val key :Int? = null
map.put(key, 1) // <--- WON'T COMPILE [Type mismatch: inferred type was Int? but Int was expected]
map.remove(key)
```

Nevertheless, I think you are right by wondering about that method being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually asking this question helped to find [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885615/8132069) question with explanation. In short, what actually happens is call of the extension function which have it's own type inference.